# Need to pass 1 gameID to 9 different users (Signed up and logged in) which is created at the run time of previous request

Tags: jmeter

I have multiple requests in the same thread group and i need to pass 18 users to the 2 game id's (9 users to each gameID) and i am using counter element to create different users and gameID's.

Login Request:

42[
"get_login",
{
"uid": "EiNjkkkxgqq1ClN7gwzJEBK5XPhYKsG5",
"key": "AUEEW891WL",
"socketId":"AvKjxCGPLzgvqGxzAAb-",
"username": "",
"avatar": "",
"language": "en",
"playerMove": "",
"joinGame": "",
"replay": 0,
"gameID": 0,
"gameNo": 0,
"data": "&email=Nov${counter}@gmail.com&password=poker",
"players": 0,
"level": "",
"lastAction": "",
"game": "",
"playMoney": 1,
"role": ""
}
]

Response:

42[
"gotLogin",
{
"response": {
"playerId": 24441,
"totalWin": 0,
"points": 0,
"playerName": "672319400464",
"displayName": "DEC65",
"playerRank": "Amateur",
"playerBank": "11K",
"playerBankAmount": 11000,
"playerAvatar": "avatar1.jpg",
"playerEmail": "Nov65@gmail.com",
"playerLevel": 1,
"playerLevelStr": "Lvl. 1",
"playerLevelPrg": 0,
"playerLevelPoints": 100,
"playerGold": 0,
"playerDealerId": 1,
"playerFbId": "",
"loadVocab": "",
"dailyBonus": 0,
"token": "37333e039503825fded65f7714f04741688af294ff0a32a7c676f5c366e193de"
}
}
]

Create Game

Request:

```
42[
"create_game",
{
"uid": "Esdv7CHkwo1ATMfvY6NcWBTM5YB4d3nj",
"key": "AUEEW891WL",
"socketId":"AvKjxCGPLzgvqGxzAAb-",
"username": "611839990703",
"avatar": "avatar17.jpg",
"language": "en",
"playerMove": "",
"joinGame": "",
"replay": 0,
"gameID": 0,
"gameNo": 0,
"data": "&gameID=undefined&game=texas&playMoney=1&gameStyle=private-cashgame&tableName=TableOct${counter}&rakeRate=0&speed=60&sb=10&bb=20&tablelow=100&tablelimit=1000&videorequired=false&username=611839990703",
"players": 0,
"level": 347,
"lastAction": "",
"game": "",
"playMoney": 1,
"role": "1",
"token":"84d26de7404377dfa0ade2ff74676fd901852e19100068d43ac8a8d449f49a1c",
"playerId":"23910",
"displayName": "p10"
}
]


Response:



42[
    "createGameRsp",
    {
        "response": {
            "title": "Create Successful",
            "result": "TableOct2 was successfully created. \n GameID: 630 \n Password: ",
            "error": "",
            "game": "texas",
            "gameID": 630
        }
    }
]

Join Game:

Request:


42[
    "get_joingame",
    {
        "uid": "Esdv7CHkwo1ATMfvY6NcWBTM5YB4d3nj",
        "key": "AUEEW891WL",
        "socketId":"AvKjxCGPLzgvqGxzAAb-",
        "username":${userName}",
        "avatar": "avatar17.jpg",
        "language": "en",
        "playerMove": "",
        "joinGame": "",
        "replay": 0,
        "gameID":"${gameID}",
        "gameNo": 0,
        "data": "&seat=${counter2}&buyin=500&privateTable=2&clubId=0",
        "players": 0,
        "level": 347,
        "lastAction": "ep.playNow",
        "game": "texas",
        "playMoney": 1,
        "role": "1",
        "playerId":"${playerId}",
        "displayName": "p10",
        "seat":${counter2}
    }
]

Response:



42[
    "gotJoinGame",
    {
        "game": "texas",
        "gameID": "630",
        "response": {
            "error": ""
        }
    }
]



Right now i am able to pass one game id to only one user. But i need to pass one game id to 9 users. How is it possible?
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) on variables:

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads

So if you extract the `gameID` by one thread (virtual user) - it will be available only to this thread. If you want to use the value by other virtual user(s) - you need to convert it into a JMeter Property via [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function or suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

If you have 2 groups of users you can assign one `gameID` to users with even thread number and the other to odd users.

More information: [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)